# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated -Angular with dotnet Core 6

Tags: angular

I have a project (dotnet core 6 with angular front end using vs2022).  I have tested in dev environment and it is working fine.  However, after deployment, I have error in the console screen **(index):6772 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated** and the (index):6772 is **No resource with given URL found**.

I have no ideas how to debug or solve the issue.  I search for solution but I found nothing that can solve this issue.  The app is using VS2022 IDE (not Visual Studio Code).
the git of my source is git.com/d052057/webankorLarLogin if you want to check out source code.

Thanks.